# Configuración Postfix en Amazon EC2

Tags: ec2

Estoy intentando configurar una cuenta de mail en mi ec2 de Amazon, y hasta ahora puedo enviar mails, pero me llegan como Spam, y el remitente es 
ec2-user@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com

y quiero que llegue como ec2-user@midominio.com.ar
Además no recibo mails enviados desde otro servidor
Podrían ayudarme?

Estoy siguiendo este tutorial
https://elprespufferfish.net/blog/aws,mail/2015/09/03/mail-server-ec2.html

Answer (score 0):

Debes tener correctamente configurado los DNS para tu dominio, verifica que los registros MX esten correctamente direccionados a tu servidor.

Yo seguí esta guía para montar mi servidor con SSL
https://www.exratione.com/2016/05/a-mailserver-on-ubuntu-16-04-postfix-dovecot-mysql/
pued que te ayude.